# ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter notebook in vs code

Tags: python, opencv

```py
import os 
import cv2
import cvzone
from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector  # error

Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_28992\1329371883.py in <module>
      2 import cv2
      3 import cvzone
----> 4 from cvzone.PoseModule import PoseDetector

c:\clothchangr\venv\lib\site-packages\cvzone\PoseModule.py in <module>
      7 
      8 import cv2
----> 9 import mediapipe as mp
     10 
     11 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mediapipe'
```

after installing `opencv-python` and `cvzone` modules in terminal
in ipykernel venv (python 3.7.8)
still getting an error in line 4 of code

Comment: Welcome. Have you made sure the mediapipe module was installed in your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the `mediapipe` library is not installed in your system and `cvzone.PoseModule` is dependent of that module. after installing `cvzone`, you also have to install `mediapipe` library.

```
pip install cvzone
```

then:

```
pip install mediapipe
```

Then you can import the modules successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install mediapipe
```

Run it in the terminal the same way you've installed `opencv-python` and `cvzone`. This installs the missing `mediapipe` library.

What happened and why? The [cvzone](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone) package uses the [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe) library, but doesn't list it as an explicit dependency. So when you ran `pip install cvzone` it didn't install the `mediapipe` package with the eponymous module for you, hence the `ModuleImportError`.

The `cvzone` authors assumed you would have `mediapipe` already installed, I suppose. You're [not alone](https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone/issues/71) :)

---

If you're still getting the `ModuleImportError` after running `pip install`, check that you're using pip from the correct interpreter when installing `mediapipe`. You can do it with `pip -V`: if the "from" part of the output is not like `from c:\clothchangr\venv\...`, then you [haven't activated the venv properly](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#activate-a-virtual-environment).